# Conjecture on classification of $p$-divisible over the ring of integers of $\widehat{\bar{\mathbb{Q}}_p}$

Tags: nt.number-theory, arithmetic-geometry, p-adic-hodge-theory

I am reading the paper of Fargues [Quelques résultats et conjectures concernant la courbe](https://webusers.imj-prg.fr/~laurent.fargues/AuDela.pdf). In the end of this paper, there is a conjecture on the classification of $p$-divisible groups over $\scriptstyle\mathcal{O}_C$, where $C$ is a completed algebraically closed extension of $\scriptstyle\mathbb{Q}_p$. The question is (fully or partially) answered in the famous lecture notes of Scholze at Berkeley on [$p$-adic geometry](http://math.bu.edu/people/jsweinst/Math274/ScholzeLectures.pdf). In Scholze's work, he constructed the inverse of the functor $\mathcal{BT}$ as a composition of three functors as described in the diagram at the top of page 90. Each of the three functors seems to be equivalence of categories (the first one proved  in Scholze-Weinstein, second in Fargues, and the third in this lecture notes using the geometry of $Spa$ $A_{inf}$) with no restriction on $p$. But the conjecture of Fargues considers $p=2$ as a special case. Seems  $\mathcal{BT}$ fails to be an equivalence of category if we don't pass to the localized categories when $p=2$.

Is $\mathcal{BT}$ actually equivalence of categories for all $p$? If not, which of the three functors fails.

Comment: This is true and made more explicit in the new version www.math.uni-bonn.de/people/scholze/Berkeley.pdf, see Theorem 14.4.1; there is nothing special about p=2, except that the standard method of proof breaks down.